# Jenkins shows Protractor tests as successful even when they fail

Tags: jenkins, protractor, automated-tests

Jenkins shows Protractor tests as successful when the console clearly shows failure.

I have added an expect() in my code and a fail() too but just can't get the scripts to fail, to avoid false positives.

**Script code**

```
 async fillCategories(): Promise<void> {
        try {
            await this.helper.compareText(this.projectNamePath, this.projectName);
            await this.helper.compareText(this.projectStatus, 'Started');
            await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(this.verticalDots), 500);
            await this.helper.compareText(this.commonElements.lCurrentStepName, 'Categories');
            await this.helper.click(this.firstCheckbox);
            await this.helper.click(this.btnSaveAndContinue);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Something wrong while filling categories.`);
            fail(`Something wrong while filling categories.`);
            expect(`Test`).toBe('Fail');
        }
    }
```

These don't seem to have any effect at all.

```
 fail(`Something wrong while filling categories.`);
            expect(`Test`).toBe('Fail');
```

**Jenkins Console:**

```
**************************************************
*                    Failures                    *
**************************************************

1) abc Project Smoke Test should create a project in abc
  [31m- [39m[31mExpected '' to be 'QA Automation'.[39m
  [31m- [39m[31mFailed: Something wrong while filling categories.[39m
  [31m- [39m[31mExpected '2' to be 'Purposes'.[39m
  [31m- [39m[31mExpected '3' to be 'Ripts'.[39m
  [31m- [39m[31mFailed: project creation failed TimeoutError: Wait timed out after 30031ms[39m

Executed 2 of 2 specs[31m (1 FAILED)[39m in 4 mins 17 secs.
[16:02:18] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[16:02:18] I/launcher - chromeANY #01 passed
No mail will be sent out, as 'Dev Hourly Smoke Test #461' does not have a result yet. Please make sure you set a proper result in case of pipeline/build scripts.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

See success on the last line above?

**Output on Teams**

[image]

Comment: The problem is that you are using `expect` inside your reusable function. Try validation step inside your `it` block

Comment: A fail is a fail right? I am trying to understand how this works.

Comment: it doesn't have to do anything with your protractor code, attach your jenkins shell script instead

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov What is the Jenkins Shell Script? Sorry I am not familiar with it.

Comment: you're saying protractor doesn't fail jenkins jobs. So I assume you have a job for tests. Every job should have steps/script for its execution. AFAIK there are 2 types of scripts - groovy for pipelines and shell for everything else. Normally if you go to job/configure it would be under 'build' section 'execute shell' step

Comment: I am using Execute Windows batch command (under Build.) Here I am using commands like npm install, npm run tsc, etc

Answer (score 0):

so i'm using shell commands. and what did a trick for me was run protractor like this

```
ERROR=0
protractor conf.js || ERROR=1
exit $ERROR
```

if protractor passes, error remains zero, and when you `exit 0` it marks your build as successful

`|| ERROR=1` is execute only if protractor fails, overwrites the value and exits with code `1` which is failure

I hope you can take it from here and make a parallel for your case